# Is it possible to center Isotope masonry elements inside their container div?

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry, jquery-isotope, centering

Okay, I've looked over all the threads on here regarding Isotope/masonry/centering but am still not sure if this is possible. I think it might be best if I just start off with a link:

http://www.chrissvensson.info/ces85/020

The example is a little rough, but it is meant to a little chaotic (each image has random margin percentages set through php). If you reload you might get a better sense of it.

What I'm hoping to do is horizontally center all the individual divs (each containing an image) inside the larger Isotope container div. I have checked out the Centered Masonry option (http://isotope.metafizzy.co/custom-layout-modes/centered-masonry.html) on Isotope but I don't think it's really what I'm after—it appears that Centered Masonry centers a div containing all the masonry elements inside another div, but I think they still all begin along the left edge.

In other words, I am hoping to set it up so that the masonry elements don't all begin from the left edge. I thought it could also be nice if they are centered so that if the site is viewed on a mobile device, and there is just one image per row, that image would be more or less centered.

Okay, I hope this isn't too incoherent. I'm having a hard time explaining what I'm after. I'm also unsure if this is even possible. I should mention that I'm also using lazyload and Lightbox 2 in case this might be affecting things. I also tried Perfect Masonry (sorry, don't have enough reputation to post a link) but that didn't seem to help (I could very well have done something wrong…)

Thanks in advance for any help you might be able to offer. Also, if Isotope isn't the best solution for this, I'm open to other suggestions. I should mention that I'm not so great at programming, so I'm learning a lot of this as I go along.

Thank you!

Comment: Hi! This is a pretty old question, but have you found a solution for it? I need to do something the same...